# Loosing type-information by exporting constant as an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

The following approach (exporing a object) hints an error:

types.ts

```js
interface SetAppDataAction {
    type: typeof SET_APP_DATA // need to be exactly the string! not just any string
}

const SET_APP_DATA = "SET_APP_DATA"
export default { SET_APP_DATA }
```

action.ts

```js
import types from "./types";

const setAppData = (appData: IAppDataState): SetAppDataAction => {
    return {
        type: types.SET_APP_DATA, // Typescript error: TS2322: Type '{ SET_APP_DATA: string; }' is not assignable to type '"SET_APP_DATA"'
        payload: appData
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me whats going on here? Is it possible that the type information is lost by wrapping it in a object? (type before: exactly "SET_APP_DATA", afterwards only string?)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. Putting constants in objects makes the (mutable!) object property have a less specific type. You can prevent this using [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
export default { SET_APP_DATA } as const;
```

However, I would recommend that you do not default-export an object at all! Rather make use of names exports:

```
// types.ts
export const SET_APP_DATA = "SET_APP_DATA";
```

```
// action.ts
import * as types from "./types";

const setAppData = (appData: IAppDataState): SetAppDataAction => {
    return {
        type: types.SET_APP_DATA,
        payload: appData
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This is good advice. Sometimes I do like to `export default` such an object, when it is primarily used as a single value, in which case it's typically desirable to `Object.freeze` it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use explicit typing instead of relying on type inference.

```
interface SetAppDataAction {
    type: typeof SET_APP_DATA // need to be exactly the string! not just any string
}

const SET_APP_DATA = "SET_APP_DATA"
const objectToExport: { SET_APP_DATA: typeof SET_APP_DATA } =  { SET_APP_DATA }
export default objectToExport
```